# Using PHP to insert/output dates and time in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I don't know why it is so confusing, maybe it s because there are so many ways to output/input date and time with mysql and php. All I want is for users to put a date in this format

```
MM/DD/YYYY
```

and for it to output in this format

```
Month Name - Date
```

and for time, I want users to pick the time from  a select field, starting with 1:00 P.M. and incrementing down 30 minutes, so it will be 1:30 P.M., 2:00 P.M... and I want to somehow insert this into MySQL and output it as 1:30 P.M. Not sure how to do that either.

Comment: one way you could do it is to store the timestamp in mysql and then output it how you whant using php's date functions ( read more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php ).

Comment: ok that makes sense, i know how to store the current time in mysql but  how would i store a preselected time like 1:30 pm into mysql.

Comment: well depends on what do you need to do with the preselected time 1:30PM, for example if you would like to notify the user each day at 1:30PM, then the timestamp difference from 00:00 to 1:30PM would be int(48600) ...

Comment: i guess im asking how would you store something like 1:30 PM from a <select> input and output it exactly 1:30 PM  from mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to store a date format in a database and be able to display it the way you want is to use the `time()` and `date()` function.

when storing the date in your database you should use time(), it will generate a string like this -> `1300695900`. this little string contains the date and time

then you can use date to display it in any way you want:

```
$time = time();//you would normally get this from the database
date('d M Y', $time); //outputs 21 Mar 2011
date('m-d-y', $time); // outpus 03-21-2011
```

and so on...

**Edit:**
to answer your last question, you just get the different values, stick it together (concatenation) and then use strtotime()

```
$date = $_POST['date']; // eg 03/03/2011
$time = $_POST['time']; // eg 1:30
$daypart = $_POST['daypart']; // eg PM
$date_time = $date.' '.$time.' '.$daypart;
$strtime = strtotime($date_time);
echo date('d M Y - h:i', $strtime);// outputs 03 Mar 2011 - 01:30
```

Comment: ok i understand grabbing the date from the database and outputting the way you want. But lets say a user puts "3/25/2011" in a textfield, how would you store that in mysql since date is formatted in YYYY-MM-DD. Is there a php function to convert it into that format?

Comment: use the function strtotime() before sending it to the database

Comment: ok finally that worked out, so my only remaining question is still "how would you store something like 1:30 PM from a <select> input and output it exactly 1:30 PM from mysql." You've been an awesome help!